# Script queries database but doesn't get unicode characters

Tags: vbscript

I have a small vbscript file that queries a mysql database and returns a recordset which I then send to excel.

The problem is that the recordset does not return russian characters, it only returns "?" for each character.

My code is

```
dim adoConn
dim adoRS
dim n

set adoConn = Createobject("ADODB.Connection")
set adoRS = Createobject("ADODB.Recordset")

adoConn.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};SERVER=server1;DATABASE=dbtest;USER=root;PASSWORD=daveeades;OPTION=3;" 

adoRS.ActiveConnection = adoConn

n=1
if adoConn.errors.count = 0 then
'now get all necessary text comments
adoRS.Open "SELECT `tbllaunchdata`.`fldResponse` FROM `tbllaunchdata`"

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True
objExcel.Workbooks.Add

While (Not adoRS.EOF)
    objExcel.Cells(n, 1).Value = adoRS("fldResponse")
    n = n + 1
    adoRS.Movenext()
Wend
end if
adoRS.close
set adoRS=nothing
adoConn.close
set adoConn=nothing
```

Could anyone please help me with this, I just can't get the unicode characters showing in excel.

Many thanks

Dave

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible culprits.

- To start with an easy check: Start - Programs - MS Office Tools - Ms
  Office Languge Settings => Is Russian enabled?
- For completeness: can you use "show variables" or "\s" to make sure of the MySQL character_set_client/connection/database/... and the collations? (I can do tests with a strict utf8 config (on a linux machine)
- WRT comment: can you do a test like this

Air! code:

```
Dim sTest : sTest = "expected russian string"
adoRS.Open "SELECT `tbllaunchdata`.`fldResponse` FROM `tbllaunchdata`"

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True
objExcel.Workbooks.Add

objExcel.Cells(0, 1).Value = adoRS("fldResponse")
objExcel.Cells(1, 1).Value = sTest
objExcel.Cells(2, 1).Value = CStr( sTest = adoRS("fldResponse") )
```

No thanks to me: looks like the the real important item should be:

- use up-to-date software components!

Comment: I don't think it is that, as when I use Navicat to view the mysql data it all appear as expected. Also, when I add the russian text to excel through my script (and not from the recordset) it inserts correctly (I just insert a russian string)

Comment: is it anything to do with the connection string? Is there a way to tell the string that it needs to expect unicode characters?

Comment: Thanks so much for sticking with me on this! I have run the test and the first cell shows ?????? the second cell shows the correct text and the third cell shows FALSE

Comment: I have just updated to mysql odbc driver 5.1 and this seems to have fixed the problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Dave, you seemed to have already stumbled on the solution.  Full unicode support was added to the ODBC driver in version 5.1. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-odbc.html

Answer (score 0):

Hiii .. I have the sameproblem.. But i can get the currect data from DB. But while displaying it on excel cell it shows as ????...If u got any solution please let me know.. To get pass Unicode data to Ms sql server we need to Use NVarchar Data Type... with adVarWChar..

Regards,
Liyo Jose.